# mock a method with generic return type with mockito

Tags: java, generics, mockito

Here is my problem:

```
public interface Containter extends ModelElement{
     List<? extends ModelElement> getChildren();
}
```

There are several classes implementing Containter, and I want to mock them:

```
public class MockMama {
   public static <T extends Containter, Y extends ModelElement> T bornContainer(Class<T> clazz, Y ... children) {
           T container = mock(clazz);
           when(container.getChildren()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(children));
           return container;
   }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Eclipse says "The method thenReturn(List) in the type OngoingStubbing> is not applicable for the arguments (List)". I've also tried to pass locally declared variable of type  List`<? extends ModelElement>` to thenReturn but this didn't help either.

 Any help is highly appreciated and welcomed :)

Comment: Ok, it looks it can be fixed by introducing extra local var like

     List list = Arrays.asList(children);
     when(container.getChildren()).thenReturn(list);

Is there any way to do it without causing raw type warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that there's no guarantee that the type returned by getChildren() matches the type of the varargs argument to your bornContainer method.  So the compiler is right to complain about this.  Using an intermediate local variable is really turning the compiler error into a potential runtime problem.

It seems to me that your "Containter" should really be a generic class, because its behaviour depends on the type that's in the list that getChildren() returns.  Have a look at my rewrite of your example.  This has no compile errors or warnings.

```
public interface Containter<Z extends ModelElement> extends ModelElement{      
    List<Z> getChildren(); 
}

public class MockMama {    
    public static <Y extends ModelElement, T extends Containter<Y>> T bornContainer( Class<T> clazz, Y ... children) {            
        T container = mock(clazz);            
        when(container.getChildren()).thenReturn( Arrays.asList(children));            
        return container;    
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But Container really can't be generic - it should be able to return ModelElements of any type. Also i'm sorry, there was a typo in the question - there should be no Z2ModelElements, all emelents are just ModelElements. So both container's getChildren and methods generic are Y extends ModelElement, why should there be any extra guarantees?

Comment: Because the `Y` returned by `getChildren` doesn't necessarily match the `Y`s passed into `bornContainer`; and the compiler is trying to protect you from yourself.  However, if these methods should be able to deal with any type of `ModelElement`, then maybe you could drop `Y` entirely - that is, the return type of `getChildren` could be `List<ModelElement>`, and the second parameter to `bornContainer` could just be `ModelElement...`

Answer (score 0):

Usually in tests you can disregard unchecked or raw type warnings. So it is usually safe to annotate your test with a compiler directive such as `@SupressWarning("unchecked")` .

Comment: well,yes, it can be suppressed, but I can't understand why original code doesn't compile. And this makes me nervous :) I feel this is some kind of crap “You can do x, except in case y, unless y does z, in which case you can if ...” Ken Arnold talks about http://weblogs.java.net/blog/arnold/archive/2005/06/generics_consid.html